# Several questions on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

everyone, I am not familiar with ggplot2. Now I have questions on it. Here are the codes to produce one plot

```
data <- data.frame(age=sample(c("25-29","30-34"),100,rep=TRUE),ratio=rnorm(100,mean=1,sd=0.3))
library(ggplot2)
qplot(ratio, data=data, geom="bar", fill=age, binwidth=0.1)
```

[image: Pic1]

Here are my questions.
(1) How to change the color of histogram?
(2) How to put the legend in the panel?
(3) How to change the background color?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: I would study [this](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/) closely first, before asking questions that don't include anything that you've tried. Also, don't worry about it right now, but in the future, please restrict yourself to one question at a time. We try to make Q's here good resources for future Googlers, and when they are generic like this they aren't much use.

Comment: @joran Thx! I got it! But now I do not have enough time to read the whole book like Cookbook for R.

Comment: @user1784579 I for one don't have enough time to help you when you haven't made *any* effort to read the [*documentation*](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/). Sorry.

Comment: You don't need to read the entire book. Searching the internet using your questions will yield all the answers (many of them from this site).

Comment: @user1784579 learning a language like R takes a lot of time, asking us to invest the time rather then yourself is not really nice, our time is equally precious as yours. In addition, if we simply do your thinking for you, you do not learn much, and we have to do your thinking for you again next time.

Comment: @user1784579 Thx! I am new here and do not know much about this forum. I would try to learn how to raise good question and also solve my problem by searching! Thx!

Comment: I think the -8 is perhaps a tad harsh. You'll find that at times SO suffers from pile-on voting in both directions. Just remember that SO is a great place to ask a question after you've done enough research to make an attempt yourself, not before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Have a look at `scale_color_manual`, the examples should be sufficient. The general structure of tweaking any scale in ggplot2 is to use the appropriate scale function: `scale_{aes_name}_{scale_type}`, where `aes_name` can be `color`, `x`, or any other aeshetic, and where `scale_type` can be `continuous`, `discrete`, `manual`, etc.
2. Googling for `ggplot2 legend position` led me to [this link](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/). Your answer is in there.
3. Have a look at `?theme`, in particular `panel.background`. The examples there include an example of exactly what you need.

Comment: (+1) for the reversal badge ;-)